# US auditors confiscating a vague amount of pentane and neopentane, say

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

The cryptic clue is:

> US auditors confiscating a vague amount of pentane and neopentane, say

The solution is

> Isomers

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Where is this clue from?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel A recent New Scientist cryptic crossword #92 (17 Sep 2022), Google informs me...

Answer (score 11):

Explanation

> "US auditors" refers to the [IRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_Revenue_Service) which is "confiscating" (taking in) "a vague amount" (**some**) giving **I(some)RS** - this is the wordplay part.
>  "pentane and neopentane, say" - this is the definition part as the two compounds provide an example of isomers.

Comment: Excellent! Of course, IRS. I didn’t even get that far hah.